# How to add request config in PDFTron Webviewer while fetching a doc using URL?

Tags: authentication, webview, pdftron

I'm trying to use PDFNet / PDFTron WebViewer within an angular application which is hosted on server A and I want to load a PDF file from the server B.
To load that pdf file authentication is required, the server B set a cookie on my browser. So I pass the **withCredentials: true** in the GET request.

While using WebViewer I am passing that URL to **initialDoc** param of WebViewer and the API is returning 401 status code.

```
var viewerElement = $('#viewer');
var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
            type: "html5",
            path: "path/to/lib",
            streaming : "true",
            initialDoc: "**Server B URL to load pdf file**",
            documentType : "pdf",
            config: "path/to/config"
        }, viewerElement);
```

I am not able to understand where can I pass the request configs so that I will be authenticated to fetch that document.
Is there any way by which I can make the HTTP call with credentials to get the PDF file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest release of [WebViewer 2.2.2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-webviewer/7Pi1YE4dG4E/7Ds1j903CQAJ), which includes the ability to set withCredentials.

After downloading, you would need to add the following code to config.js

```
var oldLoadDocument = ReaderControl.prototype.loadDocument;
var loadDocument = function(doc, options) {
  options.withCredentials = true;
  return oldLoadDocument.call(this, doc, options);
}
ReaderControl.prototype.loadDocument = loadDocument;
```